# Cannot run container image even with image referenced on devcontainer.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I´m using the Remote Containers extension (version 0.59.0) on VS Code (version 1.35.0) on Ubuntu 18.04 and I got the following error (I removed the image id for `mycustomimage-id`) when I click on **Remote-Containers: Reopen Folder in Container**:

```
Setting up container for folder: /home/user/source/project
Run: docker exec mycustomimage-id test -d /root/.vscode-server
cannot exec in a stopped state: unknown
Run: docker exec mycustomimage-id test -d /root/.vscode-remote
Error response from daemon: Container mycustomimage-id is not running
Run: docker exec mycustomimage-id /bin/sh -c set -o noclobber ; mkdir -p '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine' && { > '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.writeMachineSettingsMarker' ; } 2> /dev/null
Error response from daemon: Container mycustomimage-id is not running
Run: docker exec mycustomimage-id /bin/sh -c (cat /etc/os-release || cat /usr/lib/os-release) 2>/dev/null
Error response from daemon: Container mycustomimage-id is not running
Run: docker exec mycustomimage-id test -d /root/.vscode-server/bin/553cfb2c2205db5f15f3ee8395bbd5cf066d357d
Error response from daemon: Container mycustomimage-id is not running
Installing VS Code Server for commit 553cfb2c2205db5f15f3ee8395bbd5cf066d357d
Run: docker exec mycustomimage-id mkdir -p /root/.vscode-server/bin/553cfb2c2205db5f15f3ee8395bbd5cf066d357d_1560180323972
Error response from daemon: Container mycustomimage-id is not running
```

My `devcontainer.json` is the following:

```
// See https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/devcontainer.json for format details.
{
    "name": "Load image",
    "context": "..",
    "image": "mycustomimage:20190531",
    "runArgs": [    
        "--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE",
        "--security-opt",
        "seccomp=unconfined",
        "-e", "REPO_TOKEN=${env.REPO_TOKEN}",
        "-e", "BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Debug",
        "--entrypoint","/bin/bash"
    ],

    "extensions": ["ms-vscode.cpptools"],
    "workspaceFolder": "/src/remoteproj",
    "workspaceMount": "source=/home/user/source/project,destination=/src/remoteproj,type=bind"  
}
```

I´ve tried with the running container and also when I don´t have any running container. How I ensure that the image referenced in the devcontainer.json is the same that the VS Code is trying to start?

Comment: I'm running into this as well and I'm completely at a loss as to what this could be.

Comment: To anyone who might stumble onto this, I'm not seeing the error after restart and also running `docker rm $(docker ps -qa)`, not sure which fixed it.